# How to deal with search that does not give any results on a webpage?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a program with some help from a few other Stack Overflow members a few days ago, and I now had a new functionality question.

So here is my code:

```
// importing a bunch of packages

public class webSearch  {
public webSearch() {
    
}

public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

public void openTestSite() {
    //driver.navigate().to(the URL for the website);
    driver.get("https://wonef.fr/try/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Explicit wait is added after the Page load
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("WoNeF"));
} 
   
public void enter(String word) {

    WebElement query_editbox =
            driver.findElement(By.id("query"));
    query_editbox.sendKeys(word);
    //AutoComplete is happening even after sending the Enter Key.
    // So, Value needs to be selected from the autocomplete
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div")));
    List<WebElement> matchedList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div"));

   // System.out.println(matchedList.size());
    for(WebElement element : matchedList){
        if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
            element.click();
        }
    }
    query_editbox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}

public void getText(String name) throws IOException  {
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div")));
    WebElement result=driver.findElement(By.id("mid"));
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(name), "utf-8"));
    writer.write(result.getText());
    writer.close();
}
```

}

It basically opens a website, types in a word, presses enter, and then saves whatever is returned to a text file.

My question is how do I deal with the program when a word is typed in but there isn't a single hit in the search. This always causes the following error in my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@class='autocomplete']/div (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
    at src.webSearch.enter(webSearch.java:43)
    at src.Engine.main(Engine.java:58)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //div[@class='autocomplete']/div
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'my-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a6d1:8cff:fece:5dae%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:248)
... 2 more
```

**New error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@id='mid']/div (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
    at src.webSearch.getText(webSearch.java:62)
    at src.Engine.main(Engine.java:57)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //div[@id='mid']/div
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'my-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a6d1:8cff:fece:5dae%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:248)
    ... 2 more
```

**NEW EDITS!
T**he following is the code I had from long ago.

import java.io.BufferedWriter;

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.ClassLoader;

import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.TimeoutException;

 

public class webSearch  {

    public webSearch() {
        
    }
    
    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
            ;

    public void openTestSite() {

    //driver.navigate().to(the URL for the website);
    driver.get("https://wonef.fr/try/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Explicit wait is added after the Page load
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("WoNeF"));
}


    public void enter(String word) {

        WebElement query_editbox =
                driver.findElement(By.id("query"));
        System.out.println("Hello");
        query_editbox.sendKeys(word);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        //AutoComplete is happening even after sending the Enter Key.
        // So, Value needs to be selected from the autocomplete
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div")));
        List<WebElement> matchedList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div"));

        System.out.println(matchedList.size());
        for(WebElement element : matchedList){
            if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
                element.click();
            }
        }
        //query_editbox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    }
    
    public void getText()  {
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div")));
        WebElement result=driver.findElement(By.id("mid"));
        System.out.println(result.getText());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/shivamsinghal/Documents/chromedriver.exe");        
        System.out.println("Hello");

        webSearch webSrcaper = new webSearch();
        webSrcaper.openTestSite();
        webSrcaper.enter("avoir");
        webSrcaper.getText();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

The following is the new error I am receiving:

```
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'ny-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a6d1:8cff:fece:5dae%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08..., userDataDir: /var/folders/pq/hvxfhc1s22x...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 71.0.3578.98, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: cbff8e41d512f5970d24017a4911ced0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:837)
    at webSearch.openTestSite(webSearch.java:41)
    at webSearch.main(webSearch.java:82)
```

Comment: You could catch the exception and then do (or not do) something based on it.

Comment: I do not see any chrome path command in your code

Comment: I do not see any auto complete though. Why do you need that string prior of clicking on enter button. I mean you already have the key , why would selenium returns it. If it is available in DOM then only Selenium can help.

Comment: What I am confused about is one thing in my code? The element is not going to even be in the matched list if nothing shows up in the search bar, right? That was my intention when I wrote it and asked about it before.

Comment: I have a main method in the engine class which has the chrome driver access given to it. Also @Kayaman, thanks for the suggestion, however, I am not sure which exception I would catch.

Comment: I'd recommend catching the exception that is being thrown. You might recognize it from being the first line of the stacktrace: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can select your desired option using below code :

```
        WebElement query_editbox = driver.findElement(By.id("query"));
        query_editbox.sendKeys("bad");
        String wordToBeSelected = "badge";
        selectOptionFromDropdown(driver, wordToBeSelected);

    private static void selectOptionFromDropdown(WebDriver driver, String wordToBeSelected) {
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,25);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".autocomplete div")));

        List<WebElement> dropdownList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".autocomplete div"));
        WebElement desiredElement = dropdownList.stream()
                                                .filter(element -> element.getAttribute("title").equals(wordToBeSelected))
                                                .findFirst().get();
        desiredElement.click();
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I think I got this part working with your suggestion and @Subburaj's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When you entered some unavailable word, then autocomplete is not happening and hence `TimeoutException` is throwing. You need to handle this exception using try catch block.So, that your execution will be continued without any Exception. If you need to add some logic when the autocomplete is not happening, then you can handle those logic in catch block.

If the AutoComplete is not displayed within 20 seconds, then we can assume that entered value is invalid.

Please find the modified code:

**enter Method**:

```
public void enter(String word) {

    WebElement query_editbox =
            driver.findElement(By.id("query"));
    query_editbox.clear();
    query_editbox.sendKeys(word);

    try{
        //AutoComplete is happening even after sending the Enter Key.
        // So, Value needs to be selected from the autocomplete
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div")));
        List<WebElement> matchedList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div"));

       // System.out.println(matchedList.size());
        for(WebElement element : matchedList){
            if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
                element.click();
            }
        }   

    }catch (TimeoutException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid Word is entered");

    }

    query_editbox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}
```

**Edit:** To Address followup Question

1. I have added the clear action in `enter` method before entering the word.you can introduce some for loop in your main method in order to execute with different words

   ```
   String[] input={};

   for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
       webSrcapper.enter(input[i]);
       webSrcapper.getText();
   }
   ```

Sample with Array List:

```
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("Word1");
    list.add("Word2");
    list.add("Word3");

    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        webSrcapper.enter(list.get(i));
        webSrcapper.getText();
    }
```

2. You can execute your test without opening the browser and it can be done using any one of the headless browsers. I would suggest to use chrome browser as Chrome headless browser by enabling the options as below.

You need to modify your webSearch  class as below

```
public class webSearch  {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public webSearch() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

**getText Method :**

```
public void getText(String name) throws IOException  {

    try{
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div")));
        WebElement result=driver.findElement(By.id("mid"));
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(name), "utf-8"));
        writer.write(result.getText());
        writer.close();
    }catch (TimeoutException e){
            System.out.println("No Result is found for the requested word");

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Sorry to bother you again, but I had one more question. Do you know how I can clear the search bar after entering one word? So, I have a for loop which goes through the words in an array, enters each word into the search bar, and saves the contents into a text file. So, do you know how I can clear the element each time?

Comment: Also, is there any way to do this without actually opening the chrome browser? I'm just wondering because that will be much more efficient.

Comment: @userNeedsHelp: I have updated the answer. Please check with the updated answer and you need to add query_editbox.clear(); before doing the sendkeys in enter Method

Comment: Thank you for the updates! I had previously done the for loop thing and am actually getting a new error. Can you please refer to the code above to see it?

Comment: @userNeedsHelp. If the invalid Word is searched, then it will not give any result.So, you need to use try catch blcok in your getText method as well. updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I had identified those problems before, but my solution was not right. But thank you so much for your help @Subburaj before and now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to know ,it is helpful:)

Comment: I actually had one more question. Sorry for not asking earlier. When I am running the code for going through a for loop, i am also saving the output from the website for each word in the array list into a different text file. I am incurring some errors with this as some are mislabelled, some are filled incorrectly, and many text files just have the same content. Can you help me see why? Thanks!

Comment: oh. Are you able to identify any pattern for that issue? Whether it is happening only for the invalid word?

Comment: it is happening with words randomly. Yes with invalid words, but also with words that aren't invalid

Comment: Actually, never mind, I was able to figure out the problem. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Hi @Subburaj, it's been an extremely long time since I asked this question; however, I am once again having issues with this same code that I once wrote during the summer. I remembered how extremely helpful you were, so could you please help me troubleshoot my code once again. Of course, anyone else who is seeing this is more than welcome to jump into the conversation!!! :) Thank you so much in advance! I have added a clearly labelled edit above if you could kindly refer to that.